# How to make 2 HtmlUnit's WebClients use same cookies?

Tags: java, htmlunit

If I create 2 WebClients in different threads, how do I make them use the same cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
webClient1.setCookieManager(cookieManager);
webClient2.setCookieManager(cookieManager);
```