# Login check using HtmlUnit

Tags: authentication, htmlunit

Hy... i want to login to some 3rd party sites using HtmlUnit. But HtmlUnit should be able to tell me whether the login attempt to the input site is successful or not. Is there any way around to perform this task using HtmlUnit. Please help ..!!!

Thanks
Usman Raza

Comment: Someone telling about login here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043745/how-to-make-2-htmlunits-webclients-use-same-cookies

Comment: Hi "user737865" i dont know if you are still exploring this issue.I have been chasing the same problem for some time now. I posted my question in the forum too.
Here is a link to it. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499889/htmlunit-determine-if-the-login-was-successful> Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently using HTMLunit to log in to a site that has a varification page and redirect. some of my code for this is:

```
//---------------------------------Login Page---------------------------------

HtmlPage PageLogin = webClient.getPage(url);
HtmlElement submitButton = (HtmlElement) PageLogin.getByXPath(Xpath To Button).get(0);
HtmlTextInput name = (HtmlTextInput) PageLogin.getElementById("UserIdInput");
HtmlPasswordInput pass = (HtmlPasswordInput)PageLogin.getElementById("ADloginPasswordInput");

    name.setText(username);
    pass.setText(password);

    System.out.println("Logging in to site");
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

   //---------------------------------Pass varified Page----------------------
    HtmlPage pagePassVarified = submitButton.click();
    System.out.println("Successfully Logged in to site");
    HtmlElement btnContinue = (HtmlElement) pagePassVarified.getElementById("BtnClickToContinue");
    //---------------------------------------------------------

    //---------------------Home Page----------------------------------
    HtmlPage pageHome = btnContinue.click();
    System.out.println("Home Page accessed");
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This code goes to a login page, adds username and passwords to text boxes, and clicks the submit button. We are next redirected to a "wait 5 seconds, or click here to continue to home page" type of page, where the continue button is clicked. Lastly we arrive at our home page that we wanted to log into. I selected the page elements by both ID and Xpath when no ID was available.

Answer (score 1):

You can have HtmlUnit check the URL, or search for a specific element on the page, more precisely one you know to be present only in one case (sucessful login / rejected).

Comment: Thanks for replying... but i want to use some generic method.... i dont want to hardcode the values of password  and user id fields... :S . i guess there is no such way in htmlunit yet.... :(

Comment: "i dont want to hardcode the values of password and user id fields... :S . i guess there is no such way in htmlunit yet" --> I don't quite get this. If you don't want to hard code them, then get them from a properties file or you can even read them from the console. In any case, htmlunit has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Like RabidFX suggested, I would suggest you to check URL but in some cases (I've seen such situations in my work experience) URL may still the same. Then, my suggestion would be checking for a specific element and it should be the login form because generally unsuccessfull login attemps redirect you to the same page that has the same login form. That would not be hard - coded solution because I hope you have found some way to get that login form with a generic way :)