# Need help login into my yahoo mail account using Htmlunit in java

Tags: java, authentication, htmlunit

I need help on trying to log into my yahoo email, using Htmlunit in java. I am getting errors, I am really new to Htmlunit. I heard this is the best tool to use for screen scraping and in order for me to do screen scraping i need to log into my intranet but I am practicing using my yahoo mail. Please help!!

```
import java.net.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class HtmlDelete {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    HtmlDelete main = new HtmlDelete();
    try {
        main.submittingForm();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HtmlDelete.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);       }
    }

    public void submittingForm() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    //webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?.intl=us&.src=ym");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form,
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("login_form");

    //final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("subbtn");
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = page1.getHtmlElementById(".save");
    final HtmlTextInput loginName = form.getInputByName("login");
    final HtmlPasswordInput loginPs = form.getInputByName("passwd");

    // Change the value of the text field
    loginName.setValueAttribute("xxxx@yahoo.com");
    loginPs.setValueAttribute("exxxxx5");

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    final String pageAsXml = page2.asText();
    System.out.println(pageAsXml);
    //webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

output

```
    Jun 19, 2013 9:31:47 AM com.att.temp.HtmlDelete main
    SEVERE: null
    ======= EXCEPTION START ========
    Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException]
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "one" of null (https://s.yimg.com/lq/lib/yui-ssl/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js#8)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:576)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1005)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:208)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:228)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:813)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:737)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:867)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:872)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1268)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:237)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:441)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
        at com.att.temp.HtmlDelete.submittingForm(HtmlDelete.java:34)
        at com.att.temp.HtmlDelete.main(HtmlDelete.java:24)

    Inside wrapped exception:
    ======= EXCEPTION START ========
    Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException]
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "one" of null (https://s.yimg.com/lq/lib/yui-ssl/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js#8)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:576)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1005)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:208)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:293)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.executeEvent(Window.java:1975)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.executeEvent(Node.java:725)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.setAndExecuteReadyState(HtmlScript.java:535)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:261)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:714)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:91)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:664)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:576)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1005)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:208)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:228)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:813)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:737)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:867)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:872)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1268)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:237)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:441)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
        at com.att.temp.HtmlDelete.submittingForm(HtmlDelete.java:34)
        at com.att.temp.HtmlDelete.main(HtmlDelete.java:24)

    ======= EXCEPTION START ========
    Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException]
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "one" of null (https://s.yimg.com/lq/lib/yui-ssl/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js#8)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1082)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:399)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:260)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:714)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:91)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:664)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:576)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1005)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:208)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:293)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.executeEvent(Window.java:1975)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.executeEvent(Node.java:725)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.setAndExecuteReadyState(HtmlScript.java:535)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:261)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:714)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:91)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:664)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:576)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1005)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:208)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:228)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:813)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:737)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:867)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:872)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1268)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:237)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:441)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
        at com.att.temp.HtmlDelete.submittingForm(HtmlDelete.java:34)
        at com.att.temp.HtmlDelete.main(HtmlDelete.java:24)
    Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "one" of null (https://s.yimg.com/lq/lib/yui-ssl/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js#8)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1006)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
        ... 44 more
    JavaScriptException value = TypeError: Cannot call method "one" of null
    ======= EXCEPTION END ========
    == CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

      function () {
          if (this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
          loadUHJS();
          }
      }

    ======= EXCEPTION END ========
    == CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

      function () {
          var seedfile = "https://s.yimg.com/lq/lib/yui-ssl/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js";
          var yui3 = document.createElement("script");
          yui3.type = "text/javascript";
          yui3.id = "seedfile";
          yui3.src = seedfile;
          var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
          head.appendChild(yui3);
          yui3.onload = function () {
          loadUHJS();
          };
          yui3.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
              loadUHJS();
          }
          };
          loadUHJS = function () {
          YUI({combine: true, comboBase: "https://s.yimg.com/lq/combo?", root: "yui-ssl/3.4.1/build/"}).use("node", "event", "event-mouseenter", "substitute", "oop", "node-focusmanager", function (Y) {
          });
          var hdJS = document.createElement("script");
          hdJS.type = "text/javascript";
          hdJS.src = "https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?kx/ucs/sts/js/442/skip-min.js&kx/ucs/uh/js/279/timestamp_library-min.js&kx/ucs/menu_utils/js/164/menu_utils_v2-min.js&kx/ucs/uh/js/267/aria_toolbar-min.js&kx/ucs/username/js/43/user_menu-min.js&kx/ucs/help/js/41/help_menu-min.js&kx/ucs/utility_link/js/20/utility_menu-min.js&kx/ucs/uh/js/262/logo_debug-min.js";
          head.appendChild(hdJS);
          };
      }

    ======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I edited my question with the errors I am receiving i took out some of the repetitive errors bc stackoverflow.com only allows 3000 characters

Answer (score 3):

Its a little strange, but the default DOM parser isn't happy with the JS that was being run on the page. Using htmlunit-2.12, I just added a specific browser version (`WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17)`) and got it to run. See the sample code:

Add the following (Note, I turned off the excess `WARNINGS`):

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
----
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);

// Get the first page
HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?.intl=us&.src=ym");

System.out.println(page1.getTitleText());
```

Which outputted:

> Yahoo! Mail: The best web-based email!

---

**EDIT**: there were a few errors that were listed (which were not listed on the original question). The errors in the question are red herrings. Once you get rid of all the noise, you get the following:

```
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[innerHTML is read-only for tag table]
```

and

```
Cannot find function attachEvent in object [object Window]
```

Comment: Yes thank you well atleast we got htmlunit to get inside the page now I how can we make it log into the yahoo website??

Comment: That's a different problem. :) Feel free to say I answer the question (as asked). Honestly, I think its pretty **[straight forward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882632/login-check-using-htmlunit)** to input data into the text boxes and press submit. Try out the example and if you have troubles, let SO know.

Comment: I tried that example you show me but I did not get it to work :( HtmlElement submitButton = (HtmlElement) PageLogin.getByXPath("//div[@name='.save']").get(0);                   HtmlElement btnContinue = (HtmlElement) pagePassVarified.getElementById(".save");       can you tell me if this ones are correct for yahoo button? I am not able to log in still